# Rename multiple files to their suffixes

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I need a way to rename a couple of files containing spaces. I have:

```
>ls
Garbage Foo1.txt
Garbage Foo2.txt
Garbage Foo3.txt
Garbage Foo4.txt
...
```

And I need:

```
Foo1.txt
Foo2.txt
Foo3.txt
Foo4.txt
...
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those few cases where the `rename` utility from the util-linux suite is up to the task. Most distributions ship this utility as `rename`; on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, `rename` is [a different, more powerful utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191643) and the util-linux utility is called `rename.ul`.

```
rename 'Garbage ' '' *.txt
```

A fully portable solution is

```
for x in *.txt; do
  mv -- "$x" "${x#'Garbage '}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With perl's rename :

```
rename -n 's/.*\s+//' *.txt
```

remove `-n` switch to do it for real. (`-n` == dry-run)

Answer (score 0):

Just using bash:

```
for file in ./*.txt; do mv -- "$file" "${file/Garbage /}"; done
```

Comment: Sorry for that. Adding `./` make it more reliable, since when not all utilities support `--` to mark ending of options. And with `awk`, even `--` doesn't work with file like `a=123`.